# Passing a rails app from development server to production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running my rails app on my laptop.

Now that things are up and running, I want to pass it all to a online server. How can I copy the app to the server, set it to Production mod and make everything work?

I have seen a lot of replies to pass an app from development to production mode on the same server but not to a different machine...

Can you point me to some online tutorial for tis? I haven't found any...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that you need to keep in mind whenever deploying to a production server:

I prefer to bundle my gems into the vendor directory `bundle --deployment`

Also, be sure to compile your assets `rake assets:precompile`.

You need to pick a web server (apache/nginx/etc) and and application server (phusion passenger).

You should check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps which covers some details on how you can deploy your website to a production machine. Also check out some of these videos http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=21.